# Python SpeechRecognition AttributeError: __exit__ with sr.Microphone()

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to use SpeechRecognition 3.5 to turn Speech into Text. I am using **Python 2.7.13**. I looked up some examples using this module, and all the examples I found included:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

But when I run this it always spits out this error

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Im not sure how to fix this, as

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
```

Is looking for an **exit** method but cannot find one. So I tried taking out the with keyword, so it looked like this:

```
source = sr.Microphone()
audio = r.listen(source)
```

But it then spits an AssertionError at me.

```
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?
```

Im not sure what to do from here. Could anyone explain to me why this doesn't work?

**Edit:**

sr.Microphone -> sr.Microphone()

**Edit 2:**

The error was caused due to me not importing PyAudio (which is required) and I did not realize. Now I can't stop it recording the microphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add,
phrase_time_limit=10 //10 seconds

eg:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
print("Say something!")
audio = r.listen(source,timeout=1,phrase_time_limit=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

with `sr.Microphone` as source:

`print("say something!")`

if you write like that then you got attribute error, so add replace `sr.Microphone` with `sr.Microphone()`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sr.Microphone() as source:
```

instead of:

```
sr.Microphone as source:
```